# when I'm run the gulp bundle command I'm getting below errors

Tags: node.js, gulp, bundle, jspm

I'm new to javascript world and I'm currecntly using jspm, gulp, typescript and babel when I run the command `gulp bundle` I'm getting this

```
[15:52:39] Finished 'build-system' after 1.95 s
[15:52:39] Finished 'build' after 2 s
[15:52:39] Starting 'bundle'...
[15:52:39] 'bundle' errored after 394 ms
[15:52:39] Error on fetch for animal.js at file:///D:/vetserve/Vetserve.Web/src/
Vetserve.Web.Appts/dist/animal.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\vetserve\Vetserve.Web
\src\Vetserve.Web.Appts\dist\animal.js.map'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: could you paste your gulp file please?

Comment: what @LimH. said, and can you make sure that `animal.js` and `animal.js.map` exist in that path.

Comment: @WilmerSaint  thanks for looking in to my issue
//gulpfile.js                                                                                                   

`// all gulp tasks are located in the ./build/tasks directory

// gulp configuration is in files in ./build directory
require('require-dir')('build/tasks');`

Comment: @WilmerSaint  thanks for looking in to my issue
animal.js is there but animal.js.map wasn't there.